# OAuth authentication is required with Twitter's API v1.1

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth, rstudio

I am doing my first tweet load into Rstudio to practice some text mining. I am using the **twitterR** package (with **Rcurl**).

My code is: `rdmTweets <- searchTwitter("#beer", n=500)`

But I get:

```
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) : 
  OAuth authentication is required with Twitter's API v1.1
```

I have Google the error a couple of times, but don't seem to get any helpful results.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964444/unauthorized-error-with-roauth/19328951#19328951). I had the same issue at resolved it this way.

Best,