# Unauthorized error with ROAuth

Tags: r, twitter-oauth, roauth

I am using the streamR package to pull tweets from the Twitter Streaming API. This was working fine till recently. Now - I am getting the error whenever I do a handshake.

```
> library(ROAuth)
> reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
> accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
> authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
> consumerKey <- "<myconsumerkey>"
> consumerSecret <- "myconsumersecret>"
> my_oauth <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,consumerSecret=consumerSecret,requestURL=reqURL,accessURL=accessURL,authURL=authURL)
> my_oauth$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
Error: Unauthorized
```

I have tried recreating a new application on dev.twitter.com and I still get the same error. I have tried changing the callback URL and the access levels - but no use. I have also tried using the master branch of ROAuth from github. Any idea where I am going wrong? I am using R 3.0.1

Comment: Is it working for you now? I am having same problem recently. But it works well in another laptop or in server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The following sequence of commands solved the problem:

```
consumerKey <- ...
consumerSecret <- ...
twitCred <- getTwitterOAuth(consumer_key= consumerKey, consumer_secret=consumerSecret)
searchTwitter()
```

Notice I didn't use `registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)`. I think if you wanna save and later load `twitCred` you have to use `registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)` after loading.

I hope this helps.

P.S. Since I am using a Mac, I didn't use the `cacert.pem` file. I think it is just required for Windows.