# I've registered my oath about 5 times now, but... (twitteR package R)

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm attempting to mine twitter data in R, and am having trouble getting started. I created a twitter account, an app in twitter developers, changed the settings to read, write, and access, created my access token, and followed instructions to the letter in registering it:

My code:

```
  > library(twitteR)
  > download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",
  +               destfile="cacert.pem")
  > requestURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
  > accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
  > authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
  > consumerKey <-"my key"      #took this part out for privacy's sake
  > consumerSecret <- "my secret"       #this too
  > twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey, consumerSecret = consumerSecret, requestURL = requestURL, accessURL = accessURL, authURL = authURL)
  > twitCred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")

 To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
 https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=zxgHXJkYAB3wQ2IVAeyJjeyid7WK6EGPfouGmlx1c
 When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here: 0010819
 > registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
   [1] TRUE
 > save(list="twitCred", file="twitteR_credentials")
```

And yet, this:

```
 > s <- searchTwitter('#United', cainfo="cacert.pem")       
   [1] "Unauthorized"
   Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) : 
   Error: Unauthorized
```

I'm about to have a temper tantrum. I'd be extremely grateful if someone could explain to me what is going wrong, or, better yet, how to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964444/unauthorized-error-with-roauth?rq=1) looks helpful. It says skip the `registerTwitterOAuth` step unless you're loading credentials from file.